# NSManagedObject Collection

Tags: ios, core-data

I'm in the process of learning how to work with Core Data.

`foo` objects are a collection of `bar` objects that share similar properties. `foo` has some of its own members, one of which is an array of `bar` objects.

In order to manage the `foo`s with Core Data, do I need to model only the `foo`s? Do they both need to be subclasses of `NSManagedObject`? I do not need undo functionality on either.

Comment: Try using a relation instead of collection, it may help. Since you're doing it database-way do it database-way

Answer (score 1):

I envision your object graph as follows:

Foo entity

- attribute1
- attribute2
- bars (one-to-many relationship)

Bar entity

- attributeA
- attributeB
- displayOrder (another attribute, an int that models the Bar's index in a hypothetical array)
- foo (one-to-one relationship)

All entities are NSManagedObjects (or a subclass).

Answer (score 0):

CoreData is just like working with Relational Model in Databases.

Define One table/entity/object(in objective-c, defined in tabular form), and use to related it with another using foreign key mechanism, or for more complex problems use third entity(called relation) i.e also a table.

Table 1: for foo's
    fooID
    barID
    barID
    .
    .
    barID
       fooAttrib1
       .
       .
       fooAttribn
       barArrayAttribID

Table 2: for bar's
       barID
       barAttrib1
       .
       .
       barAttribn

Table 3: for foo's Attribute/member(that is an array pf bar's)
       barArrayAttribID
       barID

in table 3 barArrayAttribID is mapped from table 1, and linked with as many barID, in table 2, as the array have.

Comment: That's a terrible approach to Core Data. Using foreign keys completely ignores Core Data's native relationships. Doing so makes your code much more complex than necessary. Core Data's API is very different than relational databases, and treating it like a relational database is a good way to take simple things and make them difficult.